# How to compute this line integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, line-integrals

How do you compute this integral? $$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{R \cos t} \cos(\sin t+3t)dt \quad R>0.$$ My friend sent this to me the other day, but have not made much progress so far. Maybe using line integrals would be the easiest way to go about, since it looks like it will get messy very fast. He says that the answer should be $0$ which makes me think that this thing is symmetric over $\pi/2$, but not sure.

Comment: Hi, through searchonmath I found more about this formula in this post:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782158/calculate-%3A%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B2%5Cpi-%7De%5E%7Br%7B-%7B%5Ccos-t%7D%7D%7D%5Ccos%28r%5Csin-t%2B3t%29%5Cmathrm%7Bd%7Dt%24#answer-3782199

This may be useful.

Comment: @FlavioGonzaga. The problem is very different. Anyway, thanks for the link. Cheers :-)

Comment: Are you sure you've typed the integral in correctly, or there's not some other condition on R? By some numerical integration it would seem that this doesn't go to zero, I get the same numbers as provided in the answer below.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, apparently yes this is the correct form (without the $R$ multiplying $\sin$). I will try to ask the person who sent this to me if they are absolutely sure this is the right question, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I did not obtain any formal result.*

The center of symmetry is at $t=\pi$.

What I suspect (pure intuition) is that
$$f(R)=\int_0^{2\pi} e^{R \cos (t)} \cos[3t+\sin (t)]\,dt$$ would increase "almost" exponentially since, close to $t=0$ the integrand is
$$e^R\Big[1-\frac{1}{2} (R+16)\, t^2\Big]+O\left(t^4\right)$$

Just a few numbers (by numerical integration)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
R & f(R) \\
 2 & 0.157363 \\
 3 & 1.688026 \\
 4 & 8.387231 \\
 5 & 31.62618 \\
 6 & 104.6882 \\
 7 & 322.8717 \\
 8 & 954.7903 \\
 9 & 2749.305 \\
 10 & 7777.683
\end{array}
\right)$$